# Why do I have �� in Java String?

Tags: java, string, encoding, decode

I have a string which is `decoded/encoded/encrypted` through a long process (`file writing/reading` involved).

On the beginning of my "clear-text" String after decoding I have two strange characters : ��

What is this? Why is it there? How to get rid of it?

Thanks.

edit:

This is how I write a file:

```
try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
   out.write(string.getBytes());
   out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   //handle exception
}
```

Comment: I think this is a Byte-Order Mark (BOM)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom

Comment: It's probably a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), that was created somewhere in your file writing. Show your code.

Comment: Make sure to read this before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you down vote, can I ask for a reason? Constructive criticism would improve my questions more than getting minuses.

Comment: Probably because two `??` characters is simply what the browser prints for an unknown glyph. Without knowing (a) the exact byte eg, `3F` (b) the encoding, eg, `UTF-8`, then nobody can know what those characters are.

Comment: @user5581557 `string.getBytes()` => specify an encoding in there and use the same encoding to read the file back.

Answer (score 1):

I can pretty much guarantee it's an encoding issue

1. Never use `new String(byte[])` (always pass a charset)
2. Never use `new InputStreamReader(inputStream)` (always pass a charset)
3. Never use `String.getBytes()` (always pass a charset)
4. Make sure the editor (eg notepad) is reading using the same encoding as the file was written

If you don't explicitly pass a charset, a default will be chosen. In java this will be different for UNIX/Windows (unless you explicitly set the `file.encoding` system property).